# How can I stop my apps from updating automatically (Google Play Store settings do not work for all apps)?

Tags: google-play-store, lineageos, application-autoupdate

I have set Auto-update apps to "Don't auto-update apps" in Google Play Store.
That works for the majority of apps (except the Play Store itself).

However, according to my security software (Avast), some apps, installed after I set this setting, still update in the background, for example the YI Home camera app. "Enable auto-update" is not overridden for this app on its own page in the Play Store.

Other apps have similar behavior. Is there a way I can stop this rudeness for all apps? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

don't know if this helps you, if you're rooted you can use titanium backup and freeze the play store and services, no updates then and unfreeze when you need it (I do this on my phone)

Comment: If the apps are auto-updating than the moment you would freeze Store and Play Services it could update the app again. Furthermore, some apps are hopelessly dependent on Play Services to function.